# Devex Ribbon control prevents applicetion start - entry point was not found

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, devexpress

It does work on some machine's but wold not start on other computers.

from the code line's I see the problem is related to devex components.

this is the message I get:
[image: Error]

Comment: I know nothing about devex, but the computers it won't start on are probably missing a .NET component needed.

Comment: the problem is that I have that dll there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using gacutil -i to add the dll to the assembly cache.

Answer (score 1):

We have reviewed your old posts and here is what we have found:

It seems, you were asked about Delphi interop, but Delphi creates x86 applications.  Also, it seems, that your application fails on x64 systems.  Since, VS creates ANY CPU applications, this most likely the cause of the problem.  Try to build the application in VS for x86 platform, this should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help... This problem I have is on a 32 machine build on Visual Studio .net 3.5. I tried the build for *86 but didn't help. the msg. is still the same. I noticed that this problem is only with the ribbon bar. I made a small project with a devex button on it and it worked just fine.

Comment: Update: I see its not the dll.  if I remove the ribbon and put just a bar it's fine and it looks like they use the same dll.

Comment: Any computer 32 or 64 bit that has the devex tools installed it does work. but for my client I can't install the full package, it's against the terms...  as per my understanding I just need to put the few dll's I use in the bin folder. but that doesn't work here.